# 413 Request Entity too large error in Postman

Tags: javascript, html, email, highcharts, postman

I am trying a mail API to send the graph via Postman. When processing the body content with script src, the mail is not getting displayed.
So added the whole script in the body and when processing, getting the following error:

> 413 Request Entity too large

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4614.